# mPDF library not working with php7.2 codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mpdf

mpdf not working after upgraded CI php 5.6 project to CI php7.2 . changed mpdf library [link](https://github.com/kbs1/mpdf-5.7-php7) new version, than also it throwing many fatel errors, please any one provide mPDF library link which supported on CI Php7.2.

After solving those fatel errors in mPDF library, dowloading empty pdf file.

Comment: The important parts we need to see here is the fatal error, and what you did for fix that.

Comment: Now its working fine after solving errors, but after downloading file if i try to open file through browser giving Error: Failed to load PDF document and if i open file in system that time file opening properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the official packagist package [`mpdf/mpdf`](https://packagist.org/packages/mpdf/mpdf) with [composer](https://getcomposer.org/). mPDF version 7.1 is tested against PHP 7.2.